# "The request has already been submitted.” while working with Skydrive API in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, onedrive

I am trying to use the SkyDrive API to upload a file. I tried using the below code.GEtAccountInformaiton and GetQuotaInformaiton methods are successfully executed But it always sets this error "The request has already been submitted.” at the end (in  UploadISOFileToSkyDriveAsync() method for the field  lblMessageBar.Text ).

```
   private async void GetAccountInformations()
    {
        try
        {
            LiveOperationResult operationResult = await App.liveConnectClient.GetAsync("me");
            var jsonResult = operationResult.Result as dynamic;
            string firstName = jsonResult.first_name ?? string.Empty;
            string lastName = jsonResult.last_name ?? string.Empty;
            lblMessageBar.Text = "Welcome " + firstName + " " + lastName;
            GetQuotaInformations();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            lblMessageBar.Text = e.ToString();
        }
    }
    private async void GetQuotaInformations()
    {
        try
        {
            LiveOperationResult operationResult = await App.liveConnectClient.GetAsync("me/skydrive/quota");
            var jsonResult = operationResult.Result as dynamic;
            quota = jsonResult.quota ?? string.Empty;
            available = jsonResult.available ?? string.Empty;
            lblMessageBar.Text = "Available space in bytes: " + ConvertBytesToGigabytes(available).ToString("#.####") + "GB " + "out of bytes " + ConvertBytesToGigabytes(quota).ToString("#.####") + "GB";
            UploadISOFileToSkyDriveAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            lblMessageBar.Text = e.ToString();
        }
    }



    public async void UploadISOFileToSkyDriveAsync()
    {
        try
        {


            //http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/SkyDrive_-_How_to_upload_content_on_Windows_Phone
            IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("/shared/transfers/" + Constants.SkyDriveSavedLocationsFileName, FileMode.Append, fileStorage));
            //get the data from local database and write to the isolated file and then use the path of this file to saved it to skydrive..
            ObservableCollection<SavedLocationsTableEntity> SavedLocations = SavedLocationsTableEntity.GetSavedLocations();
            foreach (SavedLocationsTableEntity item in SavedLocations)
            {
                Writer.WriteLine(UtilityLib.GetGoogleURL(new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate(item.SavedLocationLatitude, item.SavedLocationLongitude, item.SavedLocationAltitude)));
            }

            Writer.Close();
            using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                fileStream = store.OpenFile("/shared/transfers/" + Constants.SkyDriveSavedLocationsFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);

                //strEncryptedFileStream = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(fileStream.ToString()).ToString();
                if (fileStream.Length == 0)
                {
                    lblMessageBar.Text = "No data to upload to SkyDrive..";
                    return;
                }
                fileStream.Close();
            }
            //remove previous calls

            var reqList = BackgroundTransferService.Requests.ToList();
            foreach (var req in reqList)
            {
                if (req.UploadLocation.Equals(new Uri(MyFilePathInIsoStore, UriKind.Relative)))
                    BackgroundTransferService.Remove(BackgroundTransferService.Find(req.RequestId));
            }

            //Make a new call to upload
            LiveOperationResult res = await App.liveConnectClient.BackgroundUploadAsync("me/skydrive", new Uri("/shared/transfers/" + Constants.SkyDriveSavedLocationsFileName, UriKind.Relative), OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
            lblMessageBar.Text = "File " + Constants.SkyDriveSavedLocationsFileName + " uploaded.";
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMessageBar.Text = "Cannot upload to SkyDrive.. " + ex.Message;
            return;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `MyFilePathInIsoStore` here:

```
if (req.UploadLocation.Equals(new Uri(MyFilePathInIsoStore
```

is not equals `"/shared/transfers/" + Constants.SkyDriveSavedLocationsFileName` here:

```
new Uri("/shared/transfers/" + Constants.SkyDriveSavedLocationsFileName, UriKind.Relative)
```

Comment: The loop  foreach (var req in reqList)
 is never executed